# Truffle test USDC transfer to contract + instantiate contracts

Tags: truffle, test

I'm writing my smart contract tests in JS and using Truffle.
I want to test a specific function in my contract that requires a token address and contract address as parameters:

```
        address _asset, //address base token, like USDC
        address _payee,
        uint8 _dueDate,
        uint256 _amount,
        bytes calldata _paymentReference,
        address _cometAddress
        )
```

When I just pass the mainnet USDC token address and mainnet Comet Address, the test errors out:

```
it("should be able to make an ERC20 payment", async () => {
    await instance.payInvoiceERC20(
      "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48", //USDC mainnet token address
      accounts[8], //setting a payee
      2,
      10000000, //10 USDC, 6 decimals for USDC token
      "0x494e56332d32343034", //payment ref. in bytes
      "0xc3d688B66703497DAA19211EEdff47f25384cdc3" //Comet Address USDC mainnet
    )
  })
```

Error message:
"*exited with an error (status 0). Reason given: Address: call to non-contract.*"

From what I read online and SO answers from 2018-2019, I understand I need to somehow instantiate the ERC20 token contract (+ Comet contract).
What is the best and fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make the USDC address configurable. Then you can deploy your own copy of the token in a testnet and use that address to simulate the payments.

Comment: Hi Ismael, thanks for your reply. Would you be able to give me an example? Concerning the Comet contract I'm sending funds to, do I need to deploy it as well? And how do I do that?

Comment: @Piji There isn't much to say, unless something specific is needed just create an ERC20 based on OpenZeppelin contracts.